# Запретить ввод символов в поле.

Tags: mobile, javascript

Доброго времени суток.
Есть такая проблема на некоторых телефонах (например sony):

Возьмем поле

```
<input type="tel" value="+7 (---) --- -- --" id="inputField-ms" name="ms">
```

Запретим ему ввод такой инструкцией:

```
var ifmc = document.getElementById("inputField-ms");

ifmc.onkeydown = function () {
    return false;
};
```

Как и следует, в браузере и на Galaxy S3 все работает как надо. Но когда беру телефон другой, послабее, напр. Sony или Huawei, то при вводе, на мгновение выскакивает в поле ввода вводимый символ, затем исчезает. Эта проблема встречается на Android 4.0.3. На iPhone все окей.

Как я могу избавиться от такого поведения, чтобы на любых телефонах не появлялся на мгновение вводимый символ?

Конечно, мне нужна операция посложнее - мне надо отслеживать то что пользователь вводит в поле, но чтобы символ вводимый не отображался, но это уже я сам.

Comment: как вариант - просто дизаблить поле ввода...

Comment: И как по вашему появится клавиатура для ввода данных?

Answer (score 1):

Сделать прозрачное поле поверх основного поля. В прозрачное поле вводим буквы, проверяем. Если всё ок, то добавляем символ в основное поле.

Comment: Как вы советуете получится ТОЛЬКО на версии Android 4.1 с обновленным движком Webkit. На более младших версиях, когда поле становится активным, оно появляется на экране со всем что есть внутри него. Т.е. поля не видно, тыкаю в ту область где лежит это поле, оно становится активным, появляется на экране и выезжает клавиатура. Проблема осталась.

Comment: Если так, то что же можно все-таки сделать? :)